# Authenticate Flask rest API

Tags: javascript, authentication, flask, token

I have a use case:
I have a static website without server side code and I want to send an email whenever someone submits a form on website.
To send an email i am using flask rest api. I have deployed the api seperately and then i am calling the api from the website using javascript.
Now I am wondering how can i protect my api?
I am new to authentication and authorization.
The website is open to all which means its a non user website and any one can submit their queries.
How can i secure my API And call the api using javascript with the required credentials or token.

Comment: Authentication/authorization is not the answer; both are made entirely moot because “*any one can submit their queries.*” A CAPTCHA is probably what you’re looking for.

Comment: But my API isn't secure and anyone can call the api directly. Instead I want to secure it. I want to call the api just from the website url only @esqew

Comment: Secure it from what? What is your specific threat model you need to defend against? If you don’t have any concept of an existing way to identify your users, what are you expecting can be magically applied to suddenly prevent people from using this in ways it wasn’t intended? When properly architected CAPTCHA will prevent API calls made en masse, what is your resistance to using it exactly?